# Is there a version of Ubuntu 12.04 without UNITY? I prefer GNOME

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome

I'm still running 10.04, and have been putting off upgrading because I don't want to have to have UNITY. I prefer GNOME, and want to keep using it.

I do want to upgrade to another LTS release, and 12.04 is the next one.  Is there a non-UNITY version of 12.04?  A 12.04 version that still uses GNOME?